# Avoid hard-coding all possibilities

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm making a Xamarin app which has a slider between 1-100. I want it to be so when the slider is at a certain number, the output will do this `valueLabel.Text = output;` I.e. it will display the contents of the output variable.

`output = p1 + p11 + p2`

```
Random r = new Random();
int countLower = r.Next(lower.Count);//I have a list called lower, im getting random values from it
int countLower1 = r.Next(lower.Count);

var p1 = lower[countLower];
var p11 = lower[countLower1];
```

For example, if the value of the slider (var cat) is 5, I want the output to have 5 things (countLower + countLower1 + countLower2 + countLower3 + countLower4) But i dont know how i can automate the creation of this code based on the slider number. I dont want to hard-code each possibility, is there any way?

I am getting the slider value as such:

```
public void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var newStep = Math.Round(e.NewValue/step);
    var cat =newStep.ToString(); 
    label.Text = cat;
}
```

Comment: You would like the possibilities to be up to 100? Meaning if the slider is at 100 your `lower` has 100 values to be randomly added?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to have `N` random things that match the value of the slider?

Comment: Based on the slider value (up to 100) I want it to create a new variable (preferably in a naming convention, e.g lower1, lower2...,lowerX etc) and assign that variable to lower[countLower]; (lowerX = lower[countLower];), then output all the lower variables (1-X)

Comment: If thats too complicated/hard, my Plan B would be making 100 lower variables, then just adding them to output based on the Slider value (again I dont know how this would be done...)

Comment: Very confusing what you trying to achieve... Normally if you have list of values you'd use `List<...>` to store them. Something similar to Enumgivity's answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45930166/477420 sounds like close to what you may want... but `output = p1 + p11 + p2 ` makes it very hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int output = Enumerable.Range(0, newStep).Select(x => lower[r.Next(lower.Count)]).Sum();
```

Comment: I tried that, however im getting this error: Error CS1929 'IEnumerable<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Sum' and the best extension method overload 'Enumerable.Sum(IEnumerable<decimal>)' requires a receiver of type 'IEnumerable<decimal>' -

Comment: use `newStep` instead of cat in `Enumerable.Range(0, newStep)`... Do you even understand this piece of code @stackman?

Comment: @stackman - Make sure you have `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code. Then it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't tested, but the idea is that for each movement on the slider, you generated `N` random numbers up to the slider value then use String.Join() to bring them all together.

```
public void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var things = new List<int>();
    var newStep = Math.Round(e.NewValue/step);
    Random r = new Random();

    for (var i = 0; i < newStep; i++) {
         things.Add(r.Next(i);     
    }

    var cat = string.Join(",", things); 
    label.Text = cat;
}
```